# Windows 10 Black Screen, No Cursor, No possible way of doing anythting at all

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade, black-screen-of-death

I'm running an Inspiron one 2330 all in one. The problem is after a messed up install of Win 10, I can no longer do anything on it. It works fine as a display, but the actual PC part of it won't do a thing. All it gives me is a blank screen, and the fan continually runs at a low setting. I can turn it on and off, but that's the extent of what I can do besides using it as a display. Anyone know what to do?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to take it in so they can do some sort of factory reset of it. They could also take your hard drive and install correctly without using the OS.

Comment: Ill try that tomorrow then. Thanks for the advice.